# No es reconocida la instancia de un módulo asociado a @ViewChild()

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

Estoy creando un formulario que contiene sub-formularios, separe cada uno de estos formularios en otros módulos y creé un método para que retornen el `FormGroup` respectivo al módulo. El modulo padre contiene n cantidad de `@ViewChild`'s identicos a esto

```
@ViewChild(
    ReportingUnitComponent, { static: true }
  ) reportingUnitForm: ReportingUnitComponent;
```

dentro del HTML Padre tengo instanciado dicho módulo

```
<app-reporting-unit></app-reporting-unit>
```

este es el módulo del sub-formulario

```
export class ReportingUnitComponent implements OnInit {

  reportingUnitForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  createGroup() : FormGroup {
    this.reportingUnitForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      entity: [''],
      jurisdiction: [''],
      unity_municipality: [''],
      medic_unit_name: [''],
      institution: [''],
      clues: ['']
    });
    return this.reportingUnitForm;
  }

}
```

Y dentro del constructor Padre llamo el método para crear dicho `FormGroup`, donde `epidemicForm` es el `FormGroup` Padre

```
constructor(
    private formBuilder:  FormBuilder
  ) {

    this.epidemicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      /** step 0 */
      reporting_unit: this.reportingUnitForm.createGroup()
    });
  }
```

Finalmente al abrir el formulario tengo este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer la inicialización en el `ngOnInit` porque en ese punto el componente al que se hace referencia ya fue creado.

```
ngOnInit(){
       this.epidemicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          /** step 0 */
          reporting_unit: this.reportingUnitForm.createGroup()
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede que no esté reconociendo el elemento hijo, te sugiero hacer la siguiente prueba

en el ViewChild usar un identificador

```
@ViewChild(
    'SubFormulario', { static: true }
  ) reportingUnitForm: ReportingUnitComponent;
```

en el componente, usar el mismo identificador

```
<app-reporting-unit #SubFormulario ></app-reporting-unit>
```